# Passing file between two servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

i have a program written in classic asp that is used to upload a picture onto a database.

this code is stored on server 1. what i want to do is save a copy of the picture in a file on server 2 for security reasons. when the user clicks on a link on the page from the code on server 1 e.g view photos, the code will link to server 2, to the folder where the images are saved and then display the images 
can anyone inform me how to do this please? any help is welcomed.

Comment: Is the file saved in a varbinary column or as a "filestream" object?

Comment: whats the difference?? im not that hot on stuff like this

Comment: with a varbinary the file will be stored inside the database as a field in the table. With a filestream the file will be stored on the disk of the server as a file & the record will only contain a pointer to the file.

Comment: ah well the file will be added to the database on server1 (showing that it has been added), and also stored as a file (.jpg) in a folder on server 2

Answer (score 0):

This is something to implement in your ASP application.

Create a network share on server 2 and grant the ASP user account read/write rights on that share. The moment you write the file to the database you can also write it to the network share.

Look into `Open "\\server2\myshare\myfile.jpg" For Binary Access` on how to write the file.